# Java Config File not specific to directory

Tags: java, configuration, ini

I am using a configuration (.ini) file with my java app. At the moment I am specifically calling the location of the dll like this.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream("C:\\myconfigfile.ini");
```

I would like to have it so the user does not have to put it into a certain directory before the program operates.

Is there a way to implement this or is this just the best practice to go with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your ini in a resources folder and load them as resources. Here's an [excellent tutorial](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2077352/smartly-load-your-properties.html) to get you started.

Comment: You win due to the tutorial, for some reason I couldn't find one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put it in the CLASSPATH and load resource as stream using the class loader.  That'll always work, even for web apps in WAR files or JARs.

Answer (score 1):

make an ini folder in your root directory, and put it in there. Then when you start your program, it's all relative to where you start from.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream(".\\ini\\myconfigfile.ini");
```

Comment: but would this work for a user. For example if I hand someone my app and the config, I want them to just run it, without moving the config file to the proper place.

Comment: You would want to include it in your bundle, be it your jar file or zip file or what have you.

Comment: In all honesty, I feel @Duffymo has the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/).
It is solving many issues around configuration files. It also supports having individual configs for each user what is imho very important for development in a team.